# Oracle HTTP server URL with no trailing slash causes redirect when HTTPS is used

Tags: apache, 301-redirect, trailing-slash, weblogic

My application is hosted in oracle weblogic 12c with OHS 12c and have SSL enabled at port 1234. URL as such

- HTTP : `http://servername.example/webName`
- HTTPS : `https://servername.example:1234/webName`

In my hosts file, I map the server IP to a dummy URL.

```
serverIP    dummyURL.example
```

Now my site can be access through `http://dummyURL.example/webName`. But I am noticing a weird behavior when access the site with HTTPS and without trailing slash, it return a status code of 301 (Moved Permanently) and the URL turn into the actual serverName. This only happen to HTTPS, not when HTTP, what could be the cause, and how can to prevent this. I want it to get routed without revealing the actual server host name.

#### Illustration

1. Access `https://dummyURL.example:1234/webName`
2. Request return Status Code : 301 Moved Permanently
3. URL get routed to `https://servername.example:1234/webName/`

Comment: I hope somebody here can answer your question, but I'm not sure that any of our regular contributors have experience with OHS.   Most of us use Apache or Nginx with some limited IIS experience.

Comment: This is my first involvement in OHS as well. I understand that OHS is based on Apache framework, so if you have any idea in Apache, feel free to share with me. :)